# Attempting to check if any of event checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, html

When the name text field is changed I want to check if it contains text, the terms are accepted and 1 or more events checkbox is checked. If this is the case I want the submit button to become enabled.

I was told that this  `document.querySelector('[name=event[]]:checked') !== null` is the way I should check if an event checkbox is checked, however, it is the only part of the code I can't get to work.

```js
function checkStuff(){
 if (document.getElementsByName("termsChkbx")[0].checked && document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value.length != 0 && document.querySelector('[name=event[]]:checked') !== null) {
  document.getElementsByName("submit")[0].disabled = false;
}
  else{
    document.getElementsByName("submit")[0].disabled = true;
  }
}

document.getElementsByName("termsChkbx")[0].addEventListener('change', (event) => {
checkStuff();
})
```

```html
<form id="bookingForm" action="javascript:alert('form submitted');" method="get">
  <section id="Events">
    <h2>Select Events</h2>
    <div class='item'>
      <span class='eventTitle'>Event number 1</span>
      <span class='eventPrice'>10.50</span>
      <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='1' data-price='10.50'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <span class='eventTitle'>Event number 2</span>
      <span class='eventPrice'>5.00</span>
      <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='2' data-price='5.00'></span>
    </div>
    <section id="Cost">
      <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="ticket" data-price="10">
      <h2>Total Price</h2>
      Total Price <input type="text" name="total" size="12">
      <p>Name<input type="text" name="name"></p>
    </section>
  <p>Terms & conditions<input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book" disabled></p>
  </section>
</form>
```

Comment: Because, as your browser also tells you in the console (`SyntaxError: '[name=event[]]:checked' is not a valid selector`), `[name=event[]]:checked` is not a valid CSS selector

Comment: I would expect `querySelector('[name=event[]]:checked')` should actually be `querySelector('[name="event[]"]:checked')`.  Since your name includes square brackets, you need to ensure that they are treated as literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is not right. You need to add quote around the value of your attribute selector :

```
document.querySelector('[name="event[]"]:checked')
```

```js
function checkStuff(){
 if (document.getElementsByName("termsChkbx")[0].checked && document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value.length != 0 && document.querySelector('[name="event[]"]:checked') !== null) {
  document.getElementsByName("submit")[0].disabled = false;
}
  else{
    document.getElementsByName("submit")[0].disabled = true;
  }
}

document.getElementsByName("termsChkbx")[0].addEventListener('change', (event) => {
checkStuff();
})
```

```html
<form id="bookingForm" action="javascript:alert('form submitted');" method="get">
  <section id="Events">
    <h2>Select Events</h2>
    <div class='item'>
      <span class='eventTitle'>Event number 1</span>
      <span class='eventPrice'>10.50</span>
      <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='1' data-price='10.50'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <span class='eventTitle'>Event number 2</span>
      <span class='eventPrice'>5.00</span>
      <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='2' data-price='5.00'></span>
    </div>
    <section id="Cost">
      <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="ticket" data-price="10">
      <h2>Total Price</h2>
      Total Price <input type="text" name="total" size="12">
      <p>Name<input type="text" name="name"></p>
    </section>
  <p>Terms & conditions<input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book" disabled></p>
  </section>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try removing the [] from the name attribute of your checkboxes. That might be messing up your logic.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='event' value='2' data-price='5.00'>
```

You'll also need to modify your javascript

```
document.querySelector('[name=event]:checked')
```

https://codepen.io/orunnals/pen/XWJVqVv

Answer (score 0):

You can use `some` to see if any one of input with `name='event[]'` is checked and input with name `termsChkbx` are checked.

```js
function checkStuff(){
    const submit = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
    const isChecked = [...document.querySelectorAll("[name='event[]'")].some(e => e.checked) && document.querySelector('[name="termsChkbx"').checked;
    submit.disabled = !isChecked;
};

document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
   .forEach(checkbox => {
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', checkStuff);
   });
```

```html
<form id="bookingForm" action="javascript:alert('form submitted');" method="get">
        <section id="Events">
          <h2>Select Events</h2>
          <div class='item'>
            <span class='eventTitle'>Event number 1</span>
            <span class='eventPrice'>10.50</span>
            <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='1' data-price='10.50'></span>
          </div>
          <div class='item'>
            <span class='eventTitle'>Event number 2</span>
            <span class='eventPrice'>5.00</span>
            <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='2' data-price='5.00'></span>
          </div>
          <section id="Cost">
            <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="ticket" data-price="10">
            <h2>Total Price</h2>
            Total Price <input type="text" name="total" size="12">
            <p>Name<input type="text" name="name"></p>
          </section>
        <p>Terms & conditions<input type="checkbox" name="termsChkbx"></p>
          <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book" disabled></p>
        </section>
      </form>
```

Comment: Why `.some()` when the selector is the only problem?

Comment: @Andreas - Provided alternative solution

Answer (score -1):

The js would look like this

```
var checkbox2 = document.getElementByName('termsChkbx'); //Get the checkbox status

    function checkStuff() {

        if ($(checkbox2).prop('checked')) {
        //Do Stuff
        }

        else {
        //Do Stuff
        }

    }
```

Comment: Throws error, unnecessary mix of vanilla JS and jQuery, doesn't fix the actual problem.